# Developing a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux

I am trying to learn Rails on my own and have been having difficulty to set it up on windows. I am now trying to dual boot my computer. I would like to ask which Linux flavor is the best to install right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Ubuntu 10.10 in a VirtualBox VM and it's great.
See these nice tutorials to install Rails on Ubuntu 10.10.:

- [Ubuntu, Ruby, RVM, Rails, and You](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you) by Ryan Bigg
- [How to Install Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0 on Ubuntu 10.10](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-install-ruby-1-9-2-and-rails-3-0-on-ubuntu-10-10-4148.html) by Peter Cooper

Answer (score 1):

I guess that would be Ubuntu. It's easy to use and there's plenty of people using it (even for Rails development).

You can check Rails Development On Ubuntu 10.04 for sample instructions how to get started
http://ascarter.net/2010/05/10/rails-development-on-ubuntu-10.04.html